# opa - error on attempt to make whiteboard

Tags: opa

so far so good with opa. I'd like to try playing around with the whiteboard code, but I'm having difficulty getting it to compile on my ec2 instance

I did:

```
wget https://github.com/hhugo/OpaWhiteBoard/tarball/master
tar -xvzf master
cd hhugo-OpaWhiteBoard-004e4f1
make
```

and then I get:

```
opa-plugin-builder -I +cairo src/opacairo/cairo.ml -o cairo
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/myhome/src/opa/whiteboard/hhugo-OpaWhiteBoard-004e4f1/cairo.opp'
/usr/lib/opa/ocaml/bin/ocamlopt.opt   -I /usr/lib/opa/static -I +cairo -c cairoMLRuntime.mli
/usr/lib/opa/ocaml/bin/ocamlopt.opt   -I /usr/lib/opa/static -I +cairo -c     cairoMLRuntime.ml
File "src/opacairo/cairo.ml", line 3, characters 22-41:
Error: Unbound module Cairo
make[1]: *** [cairoMLRuntime.cmx] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/myhome/src/opa/whiteboard/hhugo-OpaWhiteBoard-004e4f1/cairo.opp'
Error
building failure due to error(s) in source files

make: *** [cairo.opp] Error 1
```

I didn't find much by googling the error

Comment: Try installing libcairo-ocaml-dev maybe? (or something like that)